# snprintf printing giberish on microcontroller, but is fine in other environments

Tags: c, arm

I am trying to simply convert a double to a string in C. Running

```
 char printable[9];

snprintf(printable, 9, "%f", 30.356145);
```

should set printable to "30.35614". When I run this code [on an online c compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) it outputs correctly. When I output it on my Microcontroller printable equals this nonsense:

```
"\000\033\000\000\001\000\000\000\024"
```

1. Why is am I getting this this garbage data?
2. What is this garbage data?
3. How can I get snprintf to function properly?

Comment: To answer this we must know what exact framework you're using for your firmware and what C-library you use with which specs (newlib-nano?). Chances are your C-library doesn't have float / double printf supported or activated, which is normal because those functions take up space.

Comment: Please double check whether you really want that first character in the code quote. It looks like some kind of an accident.

Comment: Check the return value from `snprintf()`

Comment: The first zero (`\000` is octal zero) is probably put by the `snprintf` function as the string terminator. The remaining "garbage" data is then the contents of the otherwise uninitialized and therefore *indeterminate* array.

Comment: I'm using arm-none-eabi and KSDK_1.2.0. Not sure how to get the other information requested. 

Cannot check return value for snprintf, its optimized out. I have confirmed that it isn't negative though

Comment: Where is your build script? If I'm right and this is newlib, you need to add the linker flag `-u _printf_float` as instructed in https://community.cypress.com/docs/DOC-9389 and https://github.com/32bitmicro/newlib-nano-1.0/blob/master/newlib/README.nano#L88

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt, that did it. If you post that as an answer, I'll upvote and mark it as correct!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the output it could be seen that `snprintf` immediately terminated the string with `\0` character and left the rest untouched. Since the array was allocated on the stack and not zero-initialized, the rest of the array values are indeterminate.

As it was confirmed by @CountMurphy's comment, the problem was that the C-library `newlib-nano` was used.

On microcontrollers Flash is precious and `printf` and related functions are one of the biggest functions in the library. Thus on embedded microcontrollers, we tend to strip out unnecessary things like `float` and `double` format specifier handling code.

The issue is resolved by explicitly activating floating-point `printf` support in `newlib-nano`, as it is instructed in the official resource [here](https://github.com/32bitmicro/newlib-nano-1.0/blob/master/newlib/README.nano#L88) and [here](https://community.cypress.com/docs/DOC-9389). One way to activate support is to add the linker flag

```
-u _printf_float
```

To the final `arm-none-eabi-gcc` command. This will force the inclusion of the symbol / function `_printf_float` which subsequently makes the `%f` format specifier work as expected.